# How to remove cache while receiving firefox push notifications

Tags: firefox, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, mozilla, service-worker

I have following lines of code in my service-worker.js to handle an incoming push notification on chrome and mozilla:

```
var httpHeaders = new Headers();
    httpHeaders.append('pragma', 'no-cache');
    httpHeaders.append('cache-control', 'no-cache');

var fetchInit = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: httpHeaders,
};

// Version 0.1
console.log('Started', self);
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log('Installed', event);
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Activated', event);
});
var urlToRedirect='';
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push message', event);
  //var title = 'Push message2';
  event.waitUntil(

    fetch("http://abc/xyz/latest.json", fetchInit).then(function(res) {
        res.json().then(function(data) {
        // Show notification
                urlToRedirect = data.data.url;
                self.registration.showNotification(data.data.title, {  
                    body: data.data.body,
                    tag: data.data.tag,
                    icon: 'images/icon.png' 
                });  

            });  
        }));

    //}));
})
```

When i change something in latest.json and send a push notification, it still loads data from the old json file. How do i make sure it takes data from the updated json. For this, i used pragma and cache-control headers, and it works fine in chrome but does not work in firefox. How to make it work in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cache` parameter for the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch#Parameters) call.

For example, by setting it to `no-store`, you can bypass the cache entirely.

Read the description of `cache mode` in the [specification of the Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-cache-mode) for more details.